Addressment of recent account suspension
SE Community,
I'm writing to share my recent experience of having my account suspended and to seek opinions of the community.
Approximately three days ago, I received a notification informing me of the suspension of my account. Perplexed by this unexpected action, I promptly reached out to the moderators to understand the reason behind it. What ensued was a conversation that left me with more questions than answers.
(Post that led to the suspension. "Warning" issued here)
Here's a summary of the exchange with the moderators:



(Excuse the duplicate parts; the photos were clipped that way) Upon reviewing the moderators' explanations, I noticed a confusing discrepancy. While my edits were flagged as "trivial" and perceived as attempts to bump the questions to the top of the "Top Questions" page, similar edits made by other users were not met with the same scrutiny.
I've provided examples (Ex.1, Ex.2, Ex.3) that illustrate this inconsistency. These revisions, like mine, appear to be minor yet were not deemed as grounds for suspension.
I'm sharing this experience with the community not to contest my suspension but rather to seek your perspectives on the matter. Your feedback would be invaluable in ensuring fair and consistent moderation practices moving forward.
Should my post inadvertently violate any rules, please let me know, and I will promptly address any concerns.
Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Example 1. A single edit is made by a disinterested user to add a tag which did not exist until two years after the last edit before that. This is not an example of trivial editing made purely to bump.

Example 2. Correcting a question to include a question mark on the same day as the question was first posted. This is not an example of trivial editing made purely to bump.

Example 3. A single edit is made by a disinterested user on the same day as the question was first posted. This is not an example of trivial editing made purely to bump.

So, to be clear, none of your examples are relevant or indicate any inconsistency. More directly however, they are all done by different individuals. Where is your evidence that anybody else has enacted a pattern of using trivial edits purely to bump their posts? You are not just making a few small changes, not just to get more attention for your content, but doing so on a regular basis, after being explicitly told this was inappropriate. You showed understanding of that notice and kept doing it. What exactly do you think you should be told here, except, stop doing things you know are wrong?

@Nij I’m not sure I get your point. I would agree with you, but I got warned the very first time I made a trivial edit. There is definitely not a pattern of smaller edits, check my profile for proof.

To add to that: Say that I see a spelling mistake in an answer to my question. Am I supposed to correct it or would it be considered a trivial edit?

With thanks to Use Nij for their opinion, said just as well as I could have:

Example 1. A single edit is made by a disinterested user to add a tag which did not exist until two years after the last edit before that. This is not an example of trivial editing made purely to bump.


Example 2. Correcting a question to include a question mark on the same day as the question was first posted. This is not an example of trivial editing made purely to bump.


Example 3. A single edit is made by a disinterested user on the same day as the question was first posted. This is not an example of trivial editing made purely to bump.

Moreover, on April 27th you were asked not to keep bumping your question and it was May 1st when you were issued the initial moderator message so your assertion in comments above that "I got warned the very first time I made a trivial edit." is demonstrably untrue.
In fact, after you were asked in comments not to keep bumping your own answer, you went on to do so 7 times.
Lastly, I'd like to address the one question made in comments here:

Say that I see a spelling mistake in an answer to my question. Am I supposed to correct it or would it be considered a trivial edit?

Absolutely you should, that's exactly what edits are for. Typically there are 2 scenarios:

You immediately notice a typo/spelling mistake very shortly after posting - correcting this won't bump the question, is it's just been answered anyway
You notice one or more typos/spelling mistakes in the hours/days after posting and you fix all mistakes in a single edit. This bumps the question once. No harm no foul. It's when you do it repeatedly, or on a large number of questions, that it has a negative effect on the site that we try to limit where possible.


I think I can see the other side of the story here. Understandable to not edit tons of questions at once, as it drowns out the other site activity. Though I do have one question about your answer. On April 27th I was asked to not keep doing trivial edits. Then on May 1st, I got the mod message. Wouldn’t that mean I got warned the first time I made a trivial edit, on April 27th? Said differently, I don’t recall making trivial edits before April 27th. The first (the first ~2 edits) time I did make a trivial edit I got a warning in the comments. Hope that makes sense.

Also I wanted to address this last part. “In fact, after you were asked in comments not to keep bumping your own answer, you went on to do so 7 times.” I don’t recall editing any one of my questions 7 times, even combining all of my questions. I did go on to edit other questions/answers that weren’t mine, but that shouldn’t be considered as aiming to bump the questions to the top of the list, as I didn’t ask nor answer them, so I would have no reason to bump them to the top of the list.

I only counted edits on your own answers.
